# Is this the best/proper way of replacing a tag?

Tags: php, zend-framework, substring, str-replace, strpos

In my text the user can input modules which look like this; `[[form:contact]]`, representing a module and its name; `[[module:name]`

I use the following code to retract this from the text, and split it, get the information from the database I want and replace it.

Is this the best way? It works good, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, and was wondering whay you guys would think of it...

I'm working with the Zend Framework.

This is the code:

```
$start = strpos($this->view->page->text, "[[");
$end = strpos($this->view->page->text, "]]");
$length = $end-$start+2;

$getModuleTag = substr($this->view->page->text, $start, $length);
$length = $end-$start-2;
$removeTags = substr($getModuleTag, 2, $length);

$split = strpos($removeTags, ":");

$GetModuleSort = substr($removeTags, 0, $split);
$GetModuleName = substr($removeTags, $split+1);

// Get the wanted data from the database
switch($GetModuleSort)
{
    case 'form':
        $this->result = $this->formsService->GetFormByName($GetModuleName);
        $replaceTag = $this->result->elements;
    break;
}

// TEST OUTPUT
$final = str_replace($getModuleTag, $replaceTag, $this->view->page->text);
$this->view->finalOutput = $final;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a good way to do it.

Comment: I guess not, I haven't tried it yet, but I'm thinking to limit the user by adding only one module so they can't create unlogical messy pages filled with modules that have nothing to do with each other

Comment: Then it's a good way in terms of performance, however there are ways with less code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression- depending on your needs:

```
$pattern="/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/";
$string="some string with a [[module]] in it, and [[another]] here";
$match=preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Would give an array of all the modules/identifiers:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => [[module]] [1] => [[another]] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => module [1] => another ) )
```

The first child includes the extracts as array children with the brackets (if you need these) the second child contains an array of the contents....

This would work with as many references as you wish.

Comment: Oke, thanks. The fact that it can work with multiple references is something that's interesting for the future. What I want to know is, which way is better in performance?